# Looking for Wicket repeater that works only with iterator (without knowing exact result size)

Tags: wicket

I am trying to use wicket to display results from nosql database. This means large data sets with unknown size.

I need kind of GridView with paging functionality which DataProvider relies only on iterator and estimated result size (like 100+, which could also mean 500k). Good example would be google search - pagination has max 10 pages, and you can go one by one, or jump few pages ahead/backward.

Does anybody know such component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to find lib with such data provider, so I've implemented one - its called `IterableGridView`

Here is the code: https://github.com/maciejmiklas/cyclop/tree/master/cyclop-wicket-components

Iterable Grid View is based on Wicket's `GridView`, however it does not work with `IDataProvider` but with
 `IterableDataProvider`. This new data provider relies only on plain java iterator - size information is not needed, and there is also no need to create range iterators for each page.

```
final List<String> myGridData = new ArrayList<>();
myGridData.add("value 1");
myGridData.add("value 2");

IterableDataProvider<String> iterableDataProvider = new IterableDataProvider<String>(10) {
    @Override
    protected Iterator<String> iterator() {
        return myGridData.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public IModel<String> model(String s) {
        return Model.of(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void detach() {
    }
};

IterableGridView<String> myGrid = new IterableGridView<String>("myGrid", iterableDataProvider) {
    @Override
    protected void populateEmptyItem(Item<String> item) {
        item.add(new Label("myValue"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void populateItem(Item<String> item) {
        item.add(new Label("myValue", item.getModelObject()));
    }
};

add(myGrid);

myGrid.setItemsPerPage(10);

// you have to use custom pager and not AjaxPagingNavigator
IterablePagingNavigator pager = new IterablePagingNavigator("rowNamesListPager", rowNamesList);
resultTable.add(pager);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846927/java-wicket-dataprovider-for-large-tables-size). Boris Pavlović pointed out i could use an [infinite scrolling](http://uxdesign.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/03/infinite-scrolling-get-bottom/) solution like [this](https://github.com/vineetsemwal/quickview).

But i still ended up using a regular DataView with an IDataProvider with a default wicket ajax page navigator. I limited query results to ~100 (10 per page) and cached the results in the IDataProvider and used the size() on the list. When size() returned same as Maxresults (100) then I give a warning, the user usually doesn't go beyond page 2 (also like google).

Answer (score 1):

My approach to something like that would be the following (that is using the regular DataProvider):

1. Determine the max displayed pages number (so in the google example, that would be 10 pages)
2. Whenever `size()` is called I estimate if there will be more results than `[results per page]*[current page] + [max pages]*[results per page]`;

   - if yes, then return `[results per page] * ([current page] + [max pages]) - 1`
   - else return the exact amount

That would make wicket think that there are `[current page] + [max pages]` pages worth of results at any given time. So at any given point you would only have to know if there are `[max pages]` worth of results more, rather than the exact amount of results.

The `size()` is used to determine the `first` and `count` parameter values on the `iterator()` function, as well as pagination sizes, so it doesn't have to actually be the size of the result set, it can be a value that would indicate how many results you want displayed, and worry about how many more you want displayed when you get closer to that.

However, the intended behaviour of `size()` is to display the actual size of the results, so any other components or behaviours you use on the GridView should be checked for side-effects, as they could potentially suffer from unexpected results.